Cannot seem to install virtio scsi drivers in a VM of Win server 2022
The Win server 22 VM did get the latest virtio-win ISO installed.  Im passing the entire device like so:
<controller type="scsi" index="0" model="lsilogic">
  <alias name="scsi0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x10" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
</controller>

<disk type="block" device="lun">
  <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
  <source dev="/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD161KRYZ-01AGBB0_2CHR982P" index="1"/>
  <backingStore/>
  <target dev="sdb" bus="scsi"/>
  <alias name="scsi0-0-1"/>
  <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="1"/>
</disk>

In device manager it shows up under Other devices as a SCSI controller with the yellow triangle with the ! in it.  I tried updating drivers and pointing it to D:\amd64\2k22 where the vioscsi files are and windows still didnt like that.
Am I being dense here?  Seems this should be pretty straightforward?

It seems the default option there was lsilogic and changing it to virtio made it show up in the win box as a virtio disk and it was fine then
